# Pygame: Drawing Ellipse or Rectangle based on Constructor Argument

Tags: python, constructor, sprite, pygame

I don't know if this is the correct website, but you guys have been so helpful before, I wanted to get your advice on a problem I'm having with Python and Pygame.

I am making a simple game, and only recently begun learning Python (loving it so far) and at the moment, I having a sprite constructor which I am using.  This constructor will manage my objects, but I want it to draw either an ellipse or a rectangle based on an argument passed to it.

```
#My code
class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #Variables!
    speed = 2
    indestructible = True
    #Constructor
    def __init__(self, color, width, height, name, shapeType):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        #Choose what to draw
        if shapeType == "Ellipse":
            pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image,color,[0,0,width,height])
        elif shapeType == "Rect":
            pygame.draw.rect(self.image,color,[0,0,width,height])
        elif shapeType == "":
            print("Shape type for ",name," not defined.")
            pygame.draw.rect(self.image,color,[0,0,width,height])
        #Init the Rect class for sprites
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

The coding I am using for drawing a square is below:

```
#Add 'white star' to the list
for i in range(random.randrange(100,200)):
    whiteStar = Block(white, 1, 1, "White Star", "Rect")
    whiteStar.rect.x = random.randrange(size[0])
    whiteStar.rect.y = random.randrange(size[1])
    whiteStar.speed = 2
    block_list.add(whiteStar)
    all_sprites_list.add(whiteStar)
```

This works wonderfully.  It draws a perfect little white square for me. But *this* doesn't work:

```
#Create Planet
planet = Block(green, 15,15, "Planet", "Ellipse")
planet.rect.x = random.randrange(size[0])
planet.rect.y = 30
planet.speed = 1
block_list.add(planet)
all_sprites_list.add(planet)
```

The 'planet' spawns correctly, but it does so as a square.  Why is this happening? And how can I fix it?  Should I use a bitmap to correct this?  Or is my coding wrong?

Just to clarify, I know for a fact that `self.rect = self.image.get_rect()` *does* work to draw an ellipse, because the coding below works.

```
#Not the code I'm using, but this works and proves self.rect = self.image.get_rect() is not the cause
# Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 

    # Create an image of the block, and fill it with a color.
    # This could also be an image loaded from the disk.
    self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
    self.image.fill(white)
    self.image.set_colorkey(white)
    pygame.draw.ellipse(self.image,color,[0,0,width,height])

    # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
    # image.
    # Update the position of this object by setting the values 
    # of rect.x and rect.y
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Thankyou for your help. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Block constructor, you call `self.image.fill(color)`.  That will fill the sprite's entire image with that color, so you get a rectangle.

The example code you have calls `self.image.set_colorkey(white)` after doing the fill, so that when it gets drawn, the background fill is transparent.  That's probably the fastest solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are filling the surface with the given `color`, and then drawing your shape in the same `color`. Of course it won't be visible that way, and you just get the solid-coloured surface, which is rectangular.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've given my tick to the new guy, but thanks for your input, a real life-saver there! :-)